# Android studio EditorLayout problemas

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, programación-móvil

los views de mi interfaz no se muestran en el android editorLayout ayuda, Gracias[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rDJj.png)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Te recomiendo que te pases por  [como elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para así mejorar la tuya y ayuda a los usuarios a responder de manera mas efectiva y precisa. Si tienes cualquier duda tienes toda la info en la sección de [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

Que tal la exclamación que tienes arriba del editor a la derecha se debe a un error de render por el appcompat asique lo que debes hacer es dentro del gradle:app module en depencies cambiar lo siguiente:

***implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'***

En esa linea camias el ultimo numero y lo vuelves a colocar tal y como esta después realiza el sync y listo.
Salu2